# polygon name inside point attribute table

Tags: arcgis, arcpy, arcgis-server

how to get the polygon name that contains a point in the point feature attribute table with automatic update? is there a way with attribute assistant??

I have used spatial join but it does not make automatic update when I create a new feature point or when I update point location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this easily with attribute assistant using the "INTERSECTING_FEATURE" method. See the docs for description and examples:

https://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-all-methods/#intersecting-feature

If you want the attribute assistant to trigger this method automatically on feature update/create then set the "ON_CHANGE" and "ON_CREATE" attributes to "1"(True).